# File size concern of Single Page Application with React + Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am developing a Single Page Application with React + Redux + Webpack. Webpack is great tool to package all stuffs but i couldn't figure out some pt
my application simply construct a parent page and once user select the function from top menu, particular function will launch as a new tab within the tab container and the tabs itself require interaction. let say when tab A complete something, tab B has to refresh part of the information.

My drafted idea is that each function is BIG component of React and the parent component controls which function (component) should be append to the tab container. But i imagine the problems may comes if i use Webpack to bundle the whole application into 1 .js file, the .js file size would be very HUGE even if i split the vendor source bundle into external resources

i believe it is common problem for Single Page Application by using Webpack and there should have better way to solve this.

Please kindly correct me if anything i misuse React + Webpack

Answer (score 0):

When webpack compiles/bundles your code in production mode it will be much smaller than the bundle sizes you're currently seeing.  Also if you're concerned, check out Preact (https://preactjs.com/) which is API-compatible with React but much smaller

Comment: Thanks Rich for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Webpack supports dynamic imports which can be used to load code on demand, e.g. when a top-level tab is opened. That way your initial js bundle stays small and the application can start very quickly.

https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports

Comment: Thanks Marko for your advice